# Как вытащить свойство из массива древовидных объектов в js?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос:как создать массив из title'ов?

```
let sells = [
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'apple',
    goods: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'orange',
            goods: {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'cucumber',
                    goods: {
                            id: 4,
                            title: 'pumpkin',
                           }
                   }
           }
   }
]
```

Comment: структура точно такая или будут элементы на одном уровне вложенности?

Comment: нет структура такая...вся соль во вложенности)

Comment: Оторвать руки тому кто создал такую структуру

Comment: я такая понимаю проблема решатся рекурсией? только вот не получается у меня...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, все верно, поможет рекурсия, я еще предположил что на верхнем уровне может быть не один объект, иначе не ясно засем тут массив очутился:

```js
let sells = [
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'pineapple',
    goods: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'grapes',
            goods: {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'watermelon',
                    goods: {
                            id: 4,
                            title: 'guava',
                           }
                   }
           }
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'apple',
    goods: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'orange',
            goods: {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'cucumber',
                    goods: {
                            id: 4,
                            title: 'pumpkin',
                           }
                   }
           }
   }
];

let collect = (s, acc) => {

  // если у объекта есть сво-во title поместим его в аккумулятор
  s.title && acc.push(s.title);
  
  // если у объекта есть сво-во goods вызовем для него collect, 
  //но передадим туда не пустой массив в качестве аккумулятора, 
  //а тот, кторый был уже передан в эту функцию
  s.goods && collect(s.goods, acc);
  
  // возвращаем аккумулятор
  return acc;
};
// flatMap по сути превращает массив массивов в плоский массив
// для всех объектов первого уровня вызываем функцию collect и 
// передаем туда пустой массив в качестве аккумулятора
let result = sells.flatMap(s => collect(s, []));
console.log(result);
```

---

Вот вариант с `reduce`, функция `collect` не отличается от сниппета выше, разница в том, что создается только один результирующий массив, а не по кол-ву элементов верхнего уровня...

```js
let sells = [
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'pineapple',
    goods: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'grapes'
    }
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'apple'
   }
];

let collect = (s, acc) => {
  s.title && acc.push(s.title);
  s.goods && collect(s.goods, acc);
  return acc;
};

let result = sells.reduce((acc, el) => collect(el, acc), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо, а не могли бы добавить комментариев)

Comment: @Ice вот так понятнее?)

Comment: бомба! спасибо)

Comment: `;;;;;;` - на, ты потерял :)

Comment: @Grundy да, собрал с телефона, надеюсь не сломал сниппеты

Comment: @Grundy только где еще одна, я 7 потерял

Comment: 5 минут гадал в чем секрет рекурсии)

Comment: @Дмытрык вроде кода то с гулькин нос, разгадали?

Comment: @Дмытрык секрет рекурсии в рекурсии :))))

Comment: В том и дело, что кода чуть-чуть, а рекурсия работает).  Секрет в том, что, в JS, объект передается по ссылке)

Comment: `;` пожалуйста :-) у меня они рассыпались перед отдачей :-D

Comment: `sells.flatMap(function a(good){ return good&&[good.title].concat(a(good.goods))||[]})` что-то не получается красиво :(

Answer (score 2):

В случае если нет возможности использовать рекурсию, например при очень большой вложенности, можно использовать цикл:

```
function collect(good){
    var goods = [good.title];
    while(good.goods){
        good = good.goods;
        goods.push(good.title);
    }
    return goods;
}
```

Далее использовать данную функцию также как в ответе [@Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003679/186999)

Comment: хотел это изобразить, но надо было бежать брать лопату, ставлю 3 плюса двумя руками и одной ногой

Comment: Спасибо и вам))